# How does temporal stutter use potency?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

Temporal stutter is on page 191 of the new Mage the awakening 2nd Edition.

The spell throws the victim forward for the spell's duration,  but the text makes no mention of using potency.

How does increasing the potency effect the spell

Comment: Remember that this is not the final version of the text; it is possible that Potency here is in error and that "Duration" is the proper Primary Spell Factor, as Duration is mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporal Stutter is Withstood by the target's Stamina. Each dot of the target's Stamina will thus reduce the Potency of the spell by 1. If the Potency of the spell is reduced to zero or lower, it will have no effect on the target, but will still count as an active spell for the purposes of spell control, according to p.114 of *Mage: the Awakening, Second Edition*.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have the new version of Mage, but generally if a spell does not have a listed effect for Potency (especially for Duration spells), then Potency will determine the difficulty of dispelling the effect early or otherwise overcoming the effect through other means (where applicable).

Answer (score 1):

Potency makes the spell harder for targets to Withstand. (p.114-15)